# GCC compiler void value error

Tags: c++, gcc

My GCC compiler shows"void value not ignored as it ought to be" and i haven't still found any solution for my code bellow:My details are given bellow

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class enemy
{
public:
    virtual void attack()
    {
        cout<<"Yo!!! i am the ENEMY "<<endl;
    }
};

class ninja: public enemy
{
public:
    void attack()
    {
        cout<<"I am the ninja"<<endl;
    }
};

class monster: public enemy
{
public:
    void attack()
    {
        cout<<"And, I am the monster"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ninja n;
    monster m;
    enemy *enemya = &n;
    enemy *enemyb = &m;
   *enemya -> attack();
   *enemyb -> attack();
}
```

Comment: Why `*enemya -> attack();` instead of `enemya -> attack();`?

Comment: thanks and sorry for the inconvenience @Ron

Answer (score 3):

Member access (`->`), binds tighter than unary `*`. Your calls to `attack` are equivalent to the following:

```
*(enemya -> attack());
```

You attempt to dereference a `void`, which is just plain wrong. Remove the superfluous operator.

Answer (score 0):

Because of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the expression `*enemya -> attack()` is equal to `*(enemya -> attack())`.

That is, you attempt to dereference what `enemya -> attack()` is returning, which is nothing.

It seems you are misunderstanding how pointers to object work, as you try to dereference the pointers *twice*. Either use the arrow operator `->`, or use the unary dereference operator `*` with the dot operator `.`.

I.e. either `enemya -> attack()`, or `(*enemya) . attack()`.